# How to use javascript in foundation(6)?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I am using foundation for sites using libsass.

css working fine however am unable to use any javascript components.

I see there's an app.js file which I have included in my application which online the following:

```
$(document).foundation();
```

However in the browser I get the following console error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).foundation is not a function
```

**UPDATE:**

I assumed wrongly that some how the js was already loaded like bootstrap however no foundation js files were being included so adding to my app config:

```
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/foundation/6.0.6/foundation.min.js
```

Fixed the issue, apologies for posting early.

Comment: what is the order of scripts in `<head>`?

Comment: We need to see all the scripts you load prior to app.js